# Should I try and salvage this new bathroom floor

Tags: bathroom, flooring

I recently had a trades person install a new Scyon floor in my bathroom. After he left I realized that the floor is falling away from the drain resulting in a 25mm gap at one end of the room. He's suggested that I just level the floor with a self leveling compound.

Is this an appropriate way to fix this floor, or do I need to rip it up and start again, this time ensuring that the floor joists are level before laying the floor.

[image: photo of floor showing gap]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person who did that is no tradesman. The job of installing backing in a bathroom is not delivering the materials and attaching them. The job is to level, plumb and square everything, and only then install the backing. This is 100% the installer's fault.

You can add self leveling compound, yes, and it should fix it. It's quite expensive, so make sure to calculate how much you need before starting, as the cost might be more than ripping the backer boards and reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of floors in homes are not level. Particularly older homes.

Often people confuse flat with level. Is your floor flat?  If so then that may be all you need to install your finish flooring.

Before the worker that did the installation is criticized, and a plan of action is concocted, more info is needed.

What is the finished flooring to be?

Is it paramount that the flooring be level or tilted to the drain?

Did you check the floor and have knowledge that it was not level prior to the installation?  (If not, Who was to make that determination?)

Was the need discussed prior to contracting for the install and an understanding had between both parties?

If so, was this communicated to the installer?

Bottom line here is; depending on the facts of the situation, you may be at fault here, or the installer, or both.

If the end product is not required to be level, or tilted to the drain,( only flat), then neither of you is at fault.  Finish the floor and move on.